# Aspx: Form Validation

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have an form with some divs, each div contains some inputs like one textboxt and one combobox, one of both need to be filled, if not, the form should not be able to submit. A div could be look like the following

```
<div id="div6" class="item" runat="server">
<div class="card-header card-header-divider mb-3">Sorgerecht</div>
<div class="card-body pt-2 pl-md-4 pr-md-4 pb-0">
    <div id="div6_row1" class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
            <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" Text="Sorgerecht:" ID="div6_row1_lb1" Theme="Office365" ></dx:ASPxLabel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-7">
            <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="div6_row1_ctl1" ClientInstanceName="div6_row1_ctl1" NullText="Wählen Sie das Sorgerecht aus" runat="server" Culture="de-DE" Theme="Office365"  Width="100%" ValueField="myparentkey" TextField="fld_bezeichnung">
                <ClientSideEvents ValueChanged="function(s,e){CheckSorgerecht(s);}" Init="function(s,e){CheckSorgerecht(s);}" />

            </dx:ASPxComboBox>
        </div>      
    </div>
    <!-- Adoptiveltern Herkunftsland -->
    <div id="div6_row2" class="row mb-2 div6adoptiv">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
            <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" Text="Adoptiveltern Herkunftsland Kind:" ID="div6_row2_lb1" Theme="Office365" ></dx:ASPxLabel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 text-right text-lg-left">
            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="div6_row2_ctl1" ClientInstanceName="div6_row2_ctl1" runat="server" AllowCustomText="True" Culture="de-DE" NullText="Adoptiveltern Herkunftsland Kind" Width="100%" Theme="Office365"  ShowImageInEditBox="True" ></dx:ASPxTextBox>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <!-- Sonstige -->
    <div id="div6_row3" class="row mb-2 div6sonstige">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-5">
            <dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" Text="Sonstige" ID="div6_row3_lb1" Theme="Office365" ></dx:ASPxLabel>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-7 text-right text-lg-left">
            <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="div6_row3_ctl1" ClientInstanceName="div6_row3_ctl1" runat="server" AllowCustomText="True" Culture="de-DE" NullText="Sonstige" Width="100%" Theme="Office365"  ShowImageInEditBox="True"  ></dx:ASPxTextBox>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Could you provide me with the best practise?

Many thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator?view=netframework-4.8?

Answer (score 0):

Use the RequiredFieldValidator control. For each required input field, add a RequiredFieldValidator control.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvdiv6_row1_ctl1" 
   runat="server" ControlToValidate ="div6_row1_ctl1"
   ErrorMessage="Field required"> 

</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: But not each field is required. Just one of them need to be filled.

Comment: You can place the validator control under the field that needs to be filled. Then set the ControlToValidate="the id of the required field"